# Цивилизация Майя

Tags: склонение

Можно ли сказать "Рядом с развалинами Майев"? Или все-таки "Рядом с развалинами Майя"?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, слово *майя* пишется со строчной буквы (если это не имя). Во-вторых, оно не склоняется и не изменяется.

[Орфографический словарь:](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F)

> майя, неизм. и нескл., м. (язык) и нескл., мн., ед. м. и ж. (народ)

--

> Но, слава богу, слышны и те, кто напоминает, что прошли времена древних майя, которые по итогам игры в мяч отправляли на заклание игроков то ли проигравшей, то ли выигравшей команды (тут у историков, насколько знаю, еще имеются разночтения). [Игорь Варламов. Какой футбол им не нужен // «Огонек», 2014]
>
> Увидим только развалины майя в Копане. [Сергей Митин. Из Гватемалы в Гондурас — и обратно // Труд-7, 2010.10.21]

Answer (score 0):

Плохо и так, и этак. Майя это цивилизация/народ, поэтому что "развалины майя" - не совсем грамотно. Что это означает? Пришли майя и развалились? Сравните, например, с "развалины римлян" или "развалины французов", точно так же не вполне грамотно.

Comment: Пожалуй, лучше сказать "развалины эпохи майя". Но и "развалины майя" не является ошибкой, по-моему.  *Увидим только развалины майя в Копане*. [Сергей Митин. Из Гватемалы в Гондурас — и обратно // Труд-7, 2010.10.21]

Comment: А идиш язык — плохо? А манси архитектура — тоже?

Comment: @Aer Первое – плохо. "Идиш" существительное. Второе тоже нехорошо. "Архитектура манси" намного лучше.

Comment: Но, увы или ах, реальность такова, что и идиш, и манси становятся/стали неизменяемыми прилагательными. Поэтому майя — это не только народ, но еще и прилагательное, связанное с названием народа, а значит, развалины майя допустимо, хоть может звучать странно.

Comment: @Aer Как оказалось, идиш можно склонять (я задал об этом вопрос), а в остальном согласен.